# Arrange weekdays starting on Sunday

Tags: r, lubridate

everyone!

How can I arrange weekdays, starting on Sunday, in R? I got the weekdays using lubridate's function weekdays(), but the days appears randomly (image attached) and I can't seem to find a way to sort it. I tried the arrange function, but I guess it only works with numeric values. A  bar chart looks very weird starting on Friday. This is what the code looks like:

```
my_dataset <- my_dataset %>% 
  mutate(weekDay = weekdays(Date))

my_dataset %>% 
  group_by(weekDay) %>% 
  summarise(mean_steps = mean(TotalSteps)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = weekDay, y = steps))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: weekdays_df]

[image: weekdays_plot]

Thanks!

I tried the arrange function, but I guess it only works with numeric values.

Comment: Have you Tried the as.Date() method?

Comment: you could create a DF and order _weekDays_ like so: `DF$weekDays <- factor(DF$weekDays, levels=c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"...))`

Answer (score 0):

Your weekDay-vector probably is of the class *character*. This will be arranged in alphabetical order by *ggplot*. The solution to this is to convert this character-vector into a factor-class.

There are several ways to get the x-axis in the order you would like to see. All of them mean to convert `weekDays` into a factor.

In order to come close to your example I have at first created a data frame with weekdays and some data. As those are both created randomly a seed was set to make the code reproducible.

One method is to create the data.frame with `summaries` and then to define in this DF weekdays as a factor with defined levels.

This can also be done within the ggplot-call when creating the aesthetics.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(111)

myData <- data.frame(
  weekDay = sample(weekdays(Sys.Date() + 0:6), 100, replace = TRUE),
  TotalSteps = sample(1000:8000, 100)
)

myData %>%
  group_by(weekDay) %>%
  summarise(mean_steps = mean(TotalSteps)) -> DF # new data.frame

# the following defines weekDay as a factor and also sets
# the sequence of factor levels. This sequence is then taken
# by ggplot to construct the x-axis.

DF$weekDay <- factor(DF$weekDay, levels = c(
  "Sonntag", "Montag",
  "Dienstag", "Mittwoch",
  "Donnerstag", "Freitag",
  "Samstag"
))
ggplot(DF, aes(x = weekDay, y = mean_steps)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x="")
```

[image]

```r
# the factor can also be defined within the ggplot-call
myData %>%
  group_by(weekDay) %>%
  summarise(mean_steps = mean(TotalSteps)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(weekDay, levels = c(
    "Sonntag", "Montag",
    "Dienstag", "Mittwoch",
    "Donnerstag", "Freitag",
    "Samstag"
  )), y = mean_steps)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x="")
```